# Javascript Closures - How does Execution Context, Variable/LexicalEnvironment, and Scope Chain fit together to form a Closure?

Tags: javascript

### Regarding VariableEnvironment & LexicalEnvironment, it seems that:

Every function call/execution creates a new execution context, and with it entirely new VariableEnvironment & LexicalEnvironment object instances to represent the code/variables **inside** that function. (For this post, I’ll shorthand group these two into Var/LexEnvironment)

These new Var/LexEnvironment objects also contain references to **already-created** Var/LexEnvironment objects representing the function object’s outer scope. This is the scope chain.

`VariableEnvironment` holds function scope variable state.

`LexicalEnvironment` holds block { } scope variable state.

### Full Closure Process Example:

Say we have two functions: function0 which contains function1.

When function1 is called, a new execution context is created = creates entirely new Var/LexicalEnvironment instances are created from code inside function1:

Only one VariableEnvironment instance, and  one LexicalEnvironment instance for each* block { }.

The existing lexical environments (outer) are simply pointed to. (This is what's referred to as 'the scope chain'). Run the function0 that contains function1’s outer lexical environments, and you’ll get completely new instances of outer Var/LexEnvironments.

But function1’s references to outer lexical environments don’t change. They don’t become these new Var/LexEnvironments instances.

A function’s `[[Scopes]]` property = a representation of the Var/Lexical environments that pertain to this function object = a browser's representation of the [[Environment]] property defined in the ECMA spec.

You can view this by using `console.dir(funcName)` in browser console.

What's incorrect here? What am I missing?

Tl;dr:

It seems safe to think of everything in JS code as being a property of an execution context (either a global or function or eval() execution context). Why?

- every execution context has unique lexical/var environments as properties. (New run = new ex. context = new instances of variableEnv objects = new variables with new references)
- and these lexical/var environments contain all your variables (identifier-value mappings).

```
function function0(sizevar) {
s = sizevar * 2
  return function function1() {
    console.log(s)
    console.log(sizevar);
  };
}

var size12 = function0(12);
var size14 = function0(14);
```

So from the above^, when you return an embedded function1, you’re returning a reference to a function instance/object that’s a property of one specific execution context’s lexical/variable environment.

And when function0() returns function1(),  scope chain is tied to an execution context’s state (i.e. its variableEnv), even if that execution context is done executing.

Comment: Your missing nothing. What do you think doesn't fit? Yes, all calls to a closure share its same outer environment.

Comment: I still don't get what you are asking. Your explanation does seem to be correct. Why do you think you are missing something?

Comment: Thank you @Bergi. I read a fair bit of conflicting info online regarding this and had to take reasoned guesses at certain points writing this. I do feel confident there are still gaps in my knowledge on this topic.